# ExpandableListView set max size of childView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a ExpandableListView and I want to put max size for childView and if I have more content in childView that to be available with a scroll.

The question is if I have in childView 5 items how I can set max size for childView to see only 3 rows and rows 4 and 5 to by visible only if I scroll down?

Comment: Wondering how this would work, how would you scroll within the sub-items of the [already scrolling] list view?

Comment: this is a request. On the iPhon that problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

you can make only three items visible by 
specyfying getCount() method  and putting the value to three

in the xml 
you can specify the height of the expandable list view to height that corresponds to three elements only .